# ActionBar Default Logo Has Wide Space

Tags: android, css, android-studio, icons

I'm working with `actionBar` in android and the default logo is not showing. So I have added this code to show the Logo in my `onCreate` method in `MainActivity`.

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

[image]

Why is the logo has a wide space causing the title to not be seen?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: try it actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

Comment: I tried this but the logo is gone

Comment: actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

Comment: Still the same. No changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to accomplish

If you want to change it in code call

```
setTitle("My new title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

And set the values to whatever you please.

In Manifest XML:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" 
       android:label="My new title" />
```

To enable the back button in your app use

```
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```